# Properties are not found in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, jsf

I have a Spring Boot + JSF (Primefaces) integrated project

```
git clone https://iva-nova-e-katerina@bitbucket.org/iva-nova-e-katerina/jsf-springboot.git
```

And build it with `mvn package` then run with

```
cd target
java -jar ./JSF-springboot-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

And when I check `http://localhost:8080/index.xhtml` I can see that there are no messages on the page. The messages are the strings in the properties files, which are bundled into WAR file, but it seems like Primefaces can't see them https://bitbucket.org/iva-nova-e-katerina/jsf-springboot/src/master/src/main/resources/. Could you help me to fetch this properties files inside Spring Boot application?

Comment: Have you tried what is described [here](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot)?

Comment: @WoAiNii I forgot <resource-bundle> tag https://gist.github.com/iva-nova-e-katerina/c046e5849d506061f21515932a42eab6 , but it doesn't work anyway. In the same time, everything works with pure JSF+Tomcat 9 without Spring Boot